# Как организовать пул потоков в NodeJS. worker_threads

Tags: node.js, многопоточность, worker-threads

Сейчас я делаю следующим образом:

Создаю 10 воркеров заранее,с информацией о том сколько процессов он выполняет, и при запросе на серверный рендер , я ищу или свободный или наименее задействованный воркер, и вешаю на него обработчик "message" и когда он отрендерит страницу, возвращаю промис и отсылаю ответ на клиент.

В итоге хотчу добится, что бы при рендеринге, CPU затратной операции, нода не блокировалась и не заставляла ждать других клиентов.

Вот код:

```
// main.js:
const WORKERS_NUMBER = 10
const workersMeta= []
for (let i = 0; i <= WORKERS_NUMBER; i++) {
 const worker = new Worker('./dist/server/renderHtml.js', { workerData: { id: i } })
  workersMeta.push({id: i, processes: 0, worker})
}


 function workerRenderHtml(path: string, theme?: string) {
  return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
  let readyWorkerId = [...workersMeta.map(({id, processes}) => ({id, processes}))].sort((a, b) => ((a.processes - b.processes)))[0].id
workersMeta[readyWorkerId].processes++

workersMeta[readyWorkerId].worker.postMessage({path: path, theme: theme})


workersMeta[readyWorkerId].worker.on('message', (res: any ) => {
  workersMeta[res.id].processes--
  resolve(res.html)
})
workersMeta[readyWorkerId].worker.on('error', err => reject(err))
}))
}
```

Но я уверен что это костыльно и неправильно. Как правильно реализовать пул?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Реализация пула воркеров**

Пул воркеров — это заданное количество ранее созданных воркеров, которые ожидают событие message. Как только событие происходит, воркеры выполняют работу и отправляют результат обратно.

Вот как можно создать пул воркеров из восьми рабочих потоков:

```
const pool = new WorkerPool(path.join(__dirname, './test-worker.js'), 8);
```

Если вы знакомы с ограничением параллельных операций, то знаете, что логика здесь почти одинакова.

Из фрагмента выше видно, конструктору WorkerPool передаётся количество воркеров и путь для их появления.

```
export class WorkerPool<T, N> {
private queue: QueueItem<T, N>[] = [];
private workersById: { [key: number]: Worker } = {};
private activeWorkersById: { [key: number]: boolean } = {};

public constructor(public workerPath: string, public numberOfThreads: number) 
{
  this.init();
 }
}
```

Здесь есть дополнительные свойства вроде workerById и activeWorkersById, в которых можно сохранить существующие воркеры и их идентификаторы соответственно. Также есть queue (очередь), в которой можно сохранять объекты со следующей структурой:

```
type QueueCallback = (err: any, result?: N) => void;

interface QueueItem<T, N> {
 callback: QueueCallback;
 getData: () => T;
}
```

callback — callback-функция в Node по умолчанию с ошибкой в качестве первого аргумента и возможным результатом в качестве второго. getData — это функция, передаваемая методу .run() пула воркеров (поясняется ниже), которая вызывается после начала обработки элемента. Данные, возвращаемые функцией getData(), будут переданы в рабочий поток.

Внутри метода .init() создаём воркеры и сохраняем их в стейтах:

```
private init() {
if (this.numberOfThreads < 1) {
 return null;
}

 for (let i = 0; i < this.numberOfThreads; i += 1) {
 const worker = new Worker(this.workerPath);

 this.workersById[i] = worker;
 this.activeWorkersById[i] = false;
 }
}
```

Для избежания бесконечных циклов нужно убедиться, что количество потоков больше 1. Создаём необходимое число воркеров и сохраняем их по индексу в стейте workerById. Также сохраняем информацию, работают ли они в настоящее время, в стейте activeWorkersById, который всегда по умолчанию имеет значение false.

Реализуем метод .run() для настройки задачи, которая будет запущена, как только воркер станет доступен.

```
  public run(getData: () => T) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const availableWorkerId = this.getInactiveWorkerId();

    const queueItem: QueueItem<T, N> = {
      getData,
      callback: (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
          return reject(error);
        }
return resolve(result);
      },
    };

    if (availableWorkerId === -1) {
      this.queue.push(queueItem);

      return null;
    }

    this.runWorker(availableWorkerId, queueItem);
  });
}
```

Внутри функции, переданной в промис, проверяем, есть ли доступный для обработки данных воркер, вызывая .getInactiveWorkerId():

```
    private getInactiveWorkerId(): number {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.numberOfThreads; i += 1) {
    if (!this.activeWorkersById[i]) {
      return i;
    }
  }

  return -1;
}
```

Создаём queueItem, в котором сохраняем переданную методу .run() функцию getData() в качестве callback. В этом callback разрешаем (resolve) или отклоняем (reject) промис в зависимости от того, передал ли воркер callback.

Если значение availableWorkerId равно -1, доступного воркера нет. В этом случае добавляем queueItem в queue. Если есть доступный воркер, вызываем метод .runWorker() для его выполнения.
В методе .runWorker() в стейте activeWorkersById необходимо установить, что воркер в данный момент используется. Также нужно настроить обработчики для событий message и error (после очистить их). И, наконец, отправить данные воркеру.

```
 const messageCallback = (result: N) => {
   queueItem.callback(null, result);

   cleanUp();
 };

 const errorCallback = (error: any) => {
   queueItem.callback(error);

   cleanUp();
 };

 const cleanUp = () => {
   worker.removeAllListeners('message');
   worker.removeAllListeners('error');

   this.activeWorkersById[workerId] = false;

   if (!this.queue.length) {
     return null;
   }

   this.runWorker(workerId, this.queue.shift());
 };

 worker.once('message', messageCallback);
 worker.once('error', errorCallback);

 worker.postMessage(await queueItem.getData());
}
```

Используя переданный workerId, получаем ссылку на воркер из стейта workerById. Внутри activeWorkersById устанавливаем в свойстве [workerId] значение true. Таким образом будет известно, что больше ничего не нужно запускать, пока воркер занят.

Создаём messageCallback() и errorCallback() для вызова событий message и error соответственно. Регистрируем указанные функции для обработки события и отправки данных воркеру.

Внутри функций вызываем callback в queueItem, а затем вызываем функцию cleanUp(). Убеждаемся, что обработчики событий удаляются, т. к. один и тот же воркер используется многократно. Если не удалить обработчики, произойдёт утечка памяти (память медленно исчерпается).

В стейте activeWorkersById устанавливаем для свойства [workerId] значение false и проверяем, пуста ли очередь. Если это не так, удаляем первый элемент из queue и снова вызываем воркер с другим queueItem.

Создадим воркер, который выполняет некоторые вычисления после получения данных в событии message:

```
import { isMainThread, parentPort } from 'worker_threads';

if (isMainThread) {
 throw new Error('Its not a worker');
}

const doCalcs = (data: any) => {
 const collection = [];

 for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i += 1) {
   collection[i] = Math.round(Math.random() * 100000);
 }

 return collection.sort((a, b) => {
   if (a > b) {
     return 1;
   }

   return -1;
 });
};

parentPort.on('message', (data: any) => {
 const result = doCalcs(data);

 parentPort.postMessage(result);
});
```

Потоковый воркер создаёт массив из 1 миллиона случайных чисел, а затем сортирует их.

Пример простого использования пула воркеров:

```
const pool = new WorkerPool<{ i: number }, number>(path.join(__dirname, './test-worker.js'), 8);

const items = [...new Array(100)].fill(null);

Promise.all(
 items.map(async (_, i) => {
   await pool.run(() => ({ i }));

   console.log('finished', i);
 }),
).then(() => {
 console.log('finished all');
});
```

Всё начиналось с создания пула из восьми воркеров. Затем был создан массив из 100 элементов и для каждого элемента запускалась задача в пуле воркеров. Первые восемь задач были выполнены немедленно, а остальные помещены в очередь и выполнены постепенно. Благодаря использованию пула воркеров не нужно каждый раз создавать воркер, что значительно повышает эффективность.

[Источник](https://tproger.ru/translations/guide-to-threads-in-node-js/)

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете воркеры только для того что б у вас 'html' рендерил не в одном потоке, то думаю для вас более подойдет библиотека `cluster`. А так ваш код можна сделать менее "костыльным и неправильным" заменив `const WORKERS_NUMBER = 10` на 
`const os = require('os'),
const WORKERS_NUMBER = os.cpus().length;`

Comment: Сluster используется. На каждом ядре запущенно по одному инстансу. Но суть в том что сам рендеринг блокирует ноду, вот я и думал как дальше можно увеличить пропускную способность без дополнительных ядер